# Run Selenium directly on Pydroid3 on Android

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pydroid

my goal is to run a python script that uses Selenium to manipulate the chrome browser, directly with Pydroid 3 app on my android smartphone (without a pc connection).

I followed the instructions at the link https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started/getting-started---android to download the appropriate webdriver and set it correctly for Android.

In detail the version of Chrome on my Smartphone (Samsung S10) is 108.0.5359.128 therefore, following what is indicated here:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads#h.p_ID_32
I downloaded webdriver "chromedriver_linux64.zip" present at the following link:
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=108.0.5359.71/

But following this example
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started/getting-started---android#h.p_ID_390 and running the following Python3 script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_to_chromedriver = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/chromedriver'
print('path_to_chromedriver: ', path_to_chromedriver)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chromedriver, 0, options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

or this one:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

path_to_chromedriver = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/chromedriver'
print('path_to_chromedriver: ', path_to_chromedriver)
service = Service(path_to_chromedriver)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage', 'com.android.chrome')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

I get this error:

```
path_to_chromedriver:  /storage/emulated/0/Download/ke-ce-verimme-justwatch-scraper/ke-ce-verimme-justwatch-scraper/scrapers/chromedriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 124, in <module>
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Download/ke-ce-verimme-justwatch-scraper/ke-ce-verimme-justwatch-scraper/scrapers/justwatchScraper.py", line 168, in start
    scrolledGenrePage = scrollGenrePageToTheEnd(genrePageURL)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Download/ke-ce-verimme-justwatch-scraper/ke-ce-verimme-justwatch-scraper/scrapers/justwatchScraper.py", line 47, in scrollGenrePageToTheEnd
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 106, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 117, in assert_process_still_running
    return_code = self.process.poll()
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

[Program finished]
```

Can anyone help me or suggest a workaround?